# get page contents and json_decode loading issue

Tags: php, json, facebook

I have the following code that makes a call to facebook's open graph and returns an object with shares and an id. The only issue is that I am making this call 30 times and it is taking over 9 seconds to load. Is there an easier way to get straight to the point and just get the shares so this loads faster?

```
//facebook
$fdata = file_get_contents('http://graph.facebook.com/http://theoatmeal.com/comics/127_hours');
$fdata = json_decode($fdata);
if($fdata->shares) {
    $share_count['facebook'] = $fdata->shares;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what i use for decode from graph.facebook.com

```
 <?php
 $info = "http://theoatmeal.com/comics/127_hours";
 $url = "http://graph.facebook.com/". $info . "";
$geturl = file_get_contents($url);
$info = json_decode($geturl);
{
$id = $info->id;
$shares = mysql_real_escape_string($info->shares);
?>
<?php echo $id;?><br>
<?php echo $shares; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

A good an easy way to proceed is to use the Facebook PHP SDK ([see on github](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk)). First you have to make sure the user is logged in :

```
require "facebook.php";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => YOUR_APP_ID,
    'secret' => YOUR_APP_SECRET,
));

$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
    try {
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        $user = null;
    }
}
```

If he is logged in, you are able to make API calls :

```
$result = $facebook->api(...);
```

If he is not, you have to log him in :

```
<?php if ($user): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $facebook->getLogoutUrl() ?>">Logout of Facebook</a>
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $facebook->getLogoutUrl() ?>">Login with Facebook</a>
<?php endif ?>
```

Hope that helps !

Comment: I appreciate this but I think this is a little more then I'll want to be doing for this one. I want to keep it simple and not have to load in any extra code that may cause more load time as well.

Comment: What are you trying to do ? You don't give enough information on it. What API call you want to do ?

Comment: see the edit. I'm trying to get the facebook share count. go to the URL in the file_get_contents function

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand well your question the first time so I try to give another shot.

You can use FQL to make your query :

```
$fql = 'SELECT total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="http://google.com"';
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=' . urlencode($fql));
$data = json_decode($json);
echo $data[0]->total_count;
```

Here, `total_count` gives you the number of shares for the link.

If you have several URL to query, you can make all of that in only one query by using `OR` :

```
SELECT url, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="..." OR url="..."
```

Here is an example is you want to get the number of shares for thoses 4 URLs :

```
$urls = array(
    "http://google.com",
    "http://twitter.com",
    "http://stackoverflow.com",
    "http://linkedin.com"
);

function wrap($url) {
    return 'url="' . $url . '"';
}

$fql = 'SELECT url, total_count FROM link_stat WHERE ';
$fql .= implode(" OR ", array_map("wrap", $urls));

$json = file_get_contents('https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=json&query=' . urlencode($fql));
$data = json_decode($json);
```

And `$data` is an array of 4 objects with the share number for each URL :

```
array(4) {
  [0]=> object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
    ["url"]=> string(17) "http://google.com"
    ["total_count"]=> int(1318598)
  }
  [1] => ...
  [2] => ...
  [3] => ...
}
```

Hope that helps !